# QGIS 3.32.3 AND QEPANET

Tags: qgis, plugins, qepanet

I am trying to install

[image]

the 'Qepanet' plugin in QGIS version 3.32.3-lima but am getting the below error. I am not a GIS tech and have no idea what this means and google is not giving me many answers. Could someone explain in layman terms and methods for troubleshooting?